# PHP pass mysql result to variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to pass the result of a `mysql` query to a variable that intergrades the email of our database to Mailchimp! However i don't know how to pass the `mysql` result to a variable!

More precise the query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT email, DATE_FORMAT(users.reg, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM users  
WHERE DATE(reg) = CURDATE()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo " " . $row["email"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


$data = [
    'email'     => $row["email"],
    'status'    => 'subscribed'
];

syncMailchimp($data);
```

How can I pass the result of the query to `$data` email?

Comment: By the time you get to `$data = ...`, `$row` will be `false`

Comment: you'd have to do it within the loop, since the value of $row changes each time the loop iterates. What you're doing now makes no logical sense, because your use of $row is completely out of its intended context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT email, DATE_FORMAT(users.reg, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM users  
WHERE DATE(reg) = CURDATE()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$data = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $data = [
            'email'     => $row["email"],
            'status'    => 'subscribed'
        ];
        syncMailchimp($data);
    }

} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";   
}
```

It will send all the `email` to mailchimp during the loop. 1 by 1.

Or you can use a separate loop to add it in the `syncMailchimp`:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT email, DATE_FORMAT(users.reg, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM users  
WHERE DATE(reg) = CURDATE()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$emails = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $emails[] = [
            'email'     => $row["email"],
            'status'    => 'subscribed'
        ];
    }

} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";   
}


foreach($emails as $email){
    syncMailchimp($email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop set the result in your array data like this :

```
$data = [];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$data[] = [
'email'     => $row["email"],
'status'    => 'subscribed'
];

}
```

later

```
syncMailchimp($data);
```